# Attempting to add SKNode which already has a parent

Tags: sprite-kit

I am experiencing a bug that crashes my spelling app when I attempt to add the same SKSpriteNode letter twice to a preexisting letter spot. I understand that is the default behavior but I don't want this to happen to my users if they try it.

For example I want to user to spell the word Ball. They can easily drag the SKSpriteNode letters to the correct locations (wells I am calling them) and I test if they place it in the correct spot with the code below. It works just fine. You can spell the word without problem and the game will move on to the next word to spell. However if I try to place in this example the last letter "l" in the word "Ball" in the same spot that contains the third letter (which is also "l") I get a nasty crash, but this crash will only happen if it is the same letter trying for the same spot. I can add the same letter to the scene all day long and it is fine, however this crash is likely to happen to a user if they let go of a word tile while it is over one of the wells that contains the same letter. (In the below code snippet my letterLabels have alpha values of zero so the user can't see them sitting in the wells. It is just how I am testing if it is in the correct spot or not.. Also the basic flow is the selected SKSpriteNode is dropped over the correct spot, then that SKSpriteNode is removed and a new SKSpriteNode with the same letter but different color tile is placed in the correct spot and the "well" is faded away.. If the user places a tile in the wrong well it moves back to the spot it originally sat at before dragging it.

```
    if ( [[self.selectedNode name]isEqualToString:self.letterLabel1.name] && [self.selectedNode intersectsNode:self.letterLabel1]) {


        [self.selectedNode removeAllActions];
        [self.selectedNode removeFromParent];

        SKSpriteNode *correctSprite = [[SKSpriteNode alloc]init];
        correctSprite = [self.lettersArray objectAtIndex:0];

        correctSprite.position = [self.wordWell01 position];

        SKAction *fadeOut = [SKAction fadeOutWithDuration:0.3];

        [self.letterLabel1 removeAllActions]; 
        [self.letterLabel1 removeFromParent];
        [self.wordWell01 runAction:fadeOut];
        [self.wordWell01 removeFromParent]; 


        [self addChild:correctSprite];

        matchFound = YES;
        self.removeCard--;
```

It would seem like to me when I test again for the second time the letter should have nothing in the third well to test against and just move back to the original spot.

Comment: you add a copy of that node with `copy()`  and the copy wont have any parent

Answer (score 2):

You can effectively prevent the crash by checking whether `correctSprite.parent` is nil before adding the sprite.

You're also allocating a new sprite, then replace it in the next line by getting the first one from lettersArray. In case this is part of the logic issue, in any case creating a new sprite is superfluous here.

Comment: This works in preventing the crash, but it actually adds the letter on top of the preexisting letter leaving the player unable to complete the word with the remaining letter tiles. Also how else would I get an object from the lettersArray if I can't store it in a variable? I can't just say correctSprite without allocating and initializing one right?

Comment: If you get the first object from lettersArray I'm assuming you've already put a sprite in that array in the first place. The way the code works right now is that you create a new sprite and immediately throw it away by replacing it with the one from the lettersArray.